# Update a record in future method with JSON data

Tags: apex, callout, future, update, invocable-method

From process builder getting record id and pass that in to apex.

[image]

Apex class to update the record:

```
   public class BacktoQuantum
    {
         @InvocableMethod(label='getdata' description='Get data from saltedge')
      public static void toquantum(List<String> ids)
        {
           BacktoQuantum.fromdata(ids);
           //System.debug('callback');
          
      }
       @future(callout=true)
        public static void fromdata(List<String> ids)
       {
             Http http = new Http();
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.setEndpoint('http://ussd.apmuyea.software.com/CustomerAdd_SaltEdge_CallBack.aspx');
                request.setMethod('GET');
                //request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
                request.setBody('{"data": {Saltedge Data }}');
           
                HttpResponse responseg = http.send(request);  
                System.debug(responseg.getBody());
            String ac = responseg.getBody(); //Return JSON data
          List<Loan_Application__c> app =  [Select Amount__c,Rate__c,Term_Months__c from Loan_Application__c where Id=:ids];
           if(!app.isEmpty())
           {
                    // app[0];
    // To update the JSON data in the first record of the list
//JSON data define as String ac; 
           }
            //Loan_Application__c app =  new Loan_Application__c();
           //app.SaltedgeData__c = ac;
           //System.debug('sample json' +app);
             } 
    }
```

The above apex code return a JSON data, I need to store that JSON data in salesforce field called Saltedge__c.
I'm stuck in the update.

can anyone help to me update the record?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the expected JSON data that you will received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the data by passing the record id value in a parameter.

Code

```
 Loan_Application__c app =  new Loan_Application__c(id=id);
  app.SaltedgeData__c = acc;
  update app;
```

Comment: Is this your solution?  If this is additional detail for your question, please [edit] your original post and include the detail.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to cast the response JSON string into Map<String, Object> then you can fetch the value based on key name. Let's say you are expecting this JSON structure

```
{
  "data": {
    "key":"data_you_want_to_fetch"
  }
}
```

Here is the example:

```
Map<String, Object> saltEdgeResultMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(saltEdgeResultMap.getBody());
Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>) saltEdgeResultMap.get('data');
Loan_Application__c app =  new Loan_Application__c();
app.SaltedgeData__c = (String)dataMap.get('key');
```